# .NET 3.5 SP1 and aspnet_client Crystal Reports

Tags: .net, asp.net, .net-3.5, crystal-reports

I recently (a few days ago) installed .NET 3.5 SP1 and subsequently an aspnet_client folder with a bunch of Crystal Reports support code has been injected into my .net web apps.

Anybody else experienced this?
Am I correct in saying that this is a side effect of SP1?
What is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is a side effect of Crystal Reports.  If you don't need it, remove it from your computer it is nothing but a headache.  It is safe to delete the aspnet_client folder.

Answer (score 0):

What do you need to remove? It keeps on adding that folder back to the project that I'm working on...